# Run script needing approval in Ansible

Tags: ansible, vpn, cisco

Need to automate cisco anyconnect installation with Ansible. While running installation script, it asks for agreement to terms and conditions. How can I parse "YES" to that?
The first below approach apparently works (haven't tried) but needs Python 2.6 according to this [Ansible doco](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html); I need to have Python 3 solution. Second below approach didn't work ,either.

Playbook code:

```
    - name: Install CISCO annyconnect #>>>> needs pexpect module from python2 <<<<
      become: yes
      expect:
        command: "/opt/CISCO/{{ vpn }}/vpn/vpn_install.sh"
        responses:
          Question:
            - yes
```

```
- name: Install CISCO annyconnect
  become: yes
  shell: yes | "/opt/CISCO/{{ vpn }}/vpn/vpn_install.sh"
```

Cisco VPN installation by script:

```
.
.
.

Description of Other Rights and Obligations 

Please refer to the Cisco Systems, Inc. End User License Agreement. 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/general/warranty/English/EU1KEN_.html

Do you accept the terms in the license agreement? [y/n]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution does not require python 2.6, but Python >= 2.6.

The logic behind "responses" map is that when the left-hand-side is found in the output, it will respond to the program with the right-hand-side. The idea is to look for the input prompt and when the prompt is found, respond.

So, currently your example code is looking for "Question" in the program output (which probaly won't match anything), but it should looking for some other string that tells us that it needs the input. "Do you accept" looks like a good candidate.

```
 - name: Install CISCO annyconnect #>>>> needs pexpect module from python2 <<<<
      become: yes
      expect:
        command: "/opt/CISCO/{{ vpn }}/vpn/vpn_install.sh"
        responses:
          "Do you accept": y
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.